# How can i add a video background as a banner to my website in Laravel?

Tags: html, css, laravel, sass

All I'm trying to do is to have a video background as a banner and over the video to have my logo and the navigation bar ( but transparent ).

I have tried a lot of code, but at some point, I'm getting blocked in scss files. My video is displayed too big in width and because of that, I get that scroll bar at the bottom of the page. I need the width to be at 1200px, but in the end it just doesn't work.

I'm using scss and I'm a beginner. If you have some solutions, please let me know. Do I need to compile the sass/scss in the Laravel project too? Because I have installed the node files for sass in the Laravel project and everything needs to have sass to work.

My HTML code:

`<div class="banner"> <video autoplay muted loop> <source src="img/banner.mp4" type="video/mp4"> </video> </div>`

Please, I could really use some help here.

Thank you!

Comment: Please post a specific code you tried and explain what was wrong with it, what is the expected result.

Comment: Hi there, my code html code was :     <div class="banner">
        <video autoplay muted loop>
            <source src="img/banner.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
    </div>               ,  all I'm trying to fing out is how to make this work in Laravel to have a banner with a background video runnig in the back and a transparent nav bar over it  and a logo of course .

Comment: Please try to use proper grammar. This makes reading your text more comfortable and easier to understand. You will be rewarded with more people reading your questions. Consider to use [Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/), if English is not your native language.

Answer (score 0):

What I understand from your question is you are not getting the .scss file in laravel. The thing is SASS is not understandable by browsers directly. You need to compile it so that browsers can show it. You will need to get the .css file to work.

Your short term fix would be to use a sass to css converter. You can find many services online. Then you can use the css files directly.

However, if you use SASS or any other similar preprocessor styling language often then you should setup your laravel development environment. To do that you can follow the following steps.

First of all, take all Sass files in your folder. Preferrably `/resources/assets/sass`. Then compile it using gulp. Also, you can use laravel mix. 
After that try running `npm run watch`. If you haven't already installed npm then you will need to install it.

It should compile the SASS. You should get a css file in your `/public` folder. Most probably `/public/css` folder.

Please checkout laravel [mix](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/mix) for more information regarding laravel mix.

Comment: There is no such folder /assets  in my  /resources   , in the /resources i have only   /js , /lang , /sass ,  and views

Comment: Then put it in the sass. And try to compile it.